# Addition of integers in C

Tags: c, addition

I want to create a program which asks to the user to type in two integers, from 0 - 10. The program then turns the integers into words and the result is also printed into words. 
EXAMPLE:
Please enter two integers: 2 5
two + five = seven

Comment: Did you have a question?  (You realize, don't you, that this is not a "Write my code for me" site?)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you. Show some effort.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a good guide on how to ask questions

Comment: There questions about how to convert numbers into words.  You have a rather minimal scale of problem; there's not much ambiguity about the numbers between 0 and 20 (well, once you agree on zero vs nought).  Things get trickier from 101 upwards — "one hundred and one" or "one hundred one".  And then what's the name for 1,000,000,000,000,000,000?  Oh, but you weren't worrying about big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple array along the lines of (that `...` isn't literal, I just couldn't be bothered typing out all the numbers):

```
char *nums[] = { "zero", "one", "two", ... "twenty" };
```

Then, for a given number `n` where `0 <= n <= 20`, you can output the number with a simple:

```
printf ("%s", nums[n]);
```

So, other than the input part (which is almost certainly covered elsewhere on SO), the code would be:

```
int n1 = 2, n2 = 5;
printf ("%s + %s = %s", nums[n1], nums[n2], nums[n1 + n2]);
```